# C++. Как удалить из строки повторяющиеся символы

Tags: c++

```
        #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int k,n, m ;
        string st;
        string std;
        cin >> st;
        k = st.length();


        for (n = 0; n < k; n++ ) {
            cout << st[n];
        }
        cout << endl;
        std = st;

        for (m = 0; m < k; m++) {
            cout << std[m];
        }
        cout << endl;

        for (n = 0; n < k; n++) {
            cout << st[n];
                if (st[n] == st[n + 1]) { 
                cout << " ";
            }

        }
}
```

Также в задаче нужно между одинаковыми символами поставить пробел, но это реализовать удалось. 
Уже недели 2 пытаюсь решить, около 10 часов провел за это время, но все никак не удаётся. Решил поспрашивать на форумах, и вот попал сюда.

Comment: не понятно что не получается,  Вам нужно  добавить пробел между одинаковыми символами или удалять одинаковые символы?.. Приведите пример исходной строки   и результат, который нужно получать

Comment: Нужно удалить одинаковые символы. Пробел сделан в 3 цикле for.

Comment: хорошо, но вы не сказали нужно ли сортировать?.. Или же удалить без сортировки? И пробел вы не ставите  в строку а просто выводите, и как же вы поставите пробел между одинаковыми символами, если вы одинаковые символы удаляете?

Comment: Сначала вывести слово с пробелами, затем уже из слова( без пробелов) удалить одинаковые символы и тоже вывести его .

Comment: Если нужно с сортировкой, то у вас есть уже ответ

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так

```
std::string st = "abbccccabbcccc";
std::unique_copy(st.begin(), st.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
std::cout << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

У Abyx рабочий вариант. Могу предложить свой, может быть более понятный для Вас. Если что-то непонятно, задавайте вопросы :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s, result;  //s - начальная строка, result - конечная
    char prev;   // последний неповторяющийся символ, который мы встретили
    cin >> s;
    prev = s[0];
    result += s[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i] != prev){
            prev = s[i];
            result += s[i];
        }
    }
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эта программа проверяет и удаляет только рядом стоящие, а мне нужно, чтобы проверяла всю строку. Попробовал ввести :  " qwerttqe ". Получил  -  qwertqe. А нужно qwert.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сам решил :)

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    string st,std;
    cin >> st;

    for (n = 0; n < st.size(); n++) {
        if (st[n] == st[n + 1]) {
            st.erase(n, 1); 
        }
    }
    std = st;
    for (n = 0; n < st.size(); n++) {
        for (m = n + 1; m < std.size() + 1; m++) { 
            if (st[n] == std[m]) {
                std.erase(m, 1); 
            }
        }
    }
    cout << std;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция с помощью итераторов удаляет из строки на входе повторяющиеся символы и возвращает результат

```
string DeleteDuplicates(string str) {
    for (string::iterator it1 = str.begin(); it1 != str.end(); ++it1) {
        for (string::iterator it2 = it1 + 1; it2 != str.end(); ) {
            if (*it1 == *it2) {
                str.erase(it2);
            }
            else {
                ++it2;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Удаляет из строки повторяющийся символ думаю разберешся

```
 for (int i = 0;i < k.size();) {
        if (used[k[i]])
            a.erase(i, i + 1);
        else
        {
            used[k[i]] = 1;
            ++i;
    }
```

Comment: не понял, что происходит с момента появления if  ? И erase - удаляет с элемента i по (i + 1) ?